# how do I initialize an struct type of array?

Tags: c

```
typedef struct_t struct_array[ROWS][COLS];

int main()
{
    struct_array structArray1 = {0};

}
```

I got an error saying there is a missing braces around the initializer. I know there is a bug of gcc regarding this warning. Or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `struct_array structArray1 = {{{0}}};`, the first one for the 1st dimension of the array, the 2nd one for the 2nd dimension and the third for the struct initialization. The code is right, but your GCC is buggy as stated in other answers.

Comment: I didn't say it wasn't, I just proposed a solution :)

Comment: Well, not accepting correct code doesn't make anything more or less permissive, it makes it *wrong*.

Comment: it just happen that this answer got passed my company compiler!

Comment: A single `0` will only work if the structure has only one element or OP is not using `-Wmissing-field-initializers`.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is completely correct.  And you're right that GCC has a bug, too - [it's described here](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53119).

You have a couple of choices:

1. Disable `-Wmissing-braces` for now.
2. Use empty initalizer braces (GCC extension):

   ```
   struct_array structArray1 = {};
   ```
3. Initialize one complete object.  For a three-element `struct_t`, for example:

   ```
   struct_array structArray1 = { { { 0, 0, 0 } } };
   ```
4. Specify all of the necessary braces and zeroes.  Assuming the same structure type as in #3 above, and a 2x2 array:

   ```
   struct_array structArray1 = { { { 0, 0, 0 }, { 0, 0, 0 },
                                   { 0, 0, 0 }, { 0, 0, 0 } },
                                 { { 0, 0, 0 }, { 0, 0, 0 },
                                   { 0, 0, 0 }, { 0, 0, 0 } } };
   ```
5. Use a different compiler. [clang](http://clang.llvm.org), maybe?
6. Fix the bug in GCC.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
int main(){
    struct_t structArray[ROWS][COLS];
    memset(structArray, 0, sizeof(structArray));
}
```

(memset fills it with zeroes)

Comment: That's not really an answer to the question.

Comment: Well, this one is technically nonportable.  What happens if the structure contains pointers?  `memset` sets them to all-zero, not to a null pointer.

Comment: Ah, k, didn't actually know that